# How do I keep given apps always running? Looking for how to relaunch them periodically

Tags: processes, llama

Throughout the day, my phone's kernel kills my memory-resident apps at random, probably because the phone had run out of memory.  The apps are [Backitude](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gaugler.backitude), [Dropsync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync), [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama), [MightyText](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.texty.sms), and [Screebl](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keyes.screebl.lite).  (All five apps run as background services, yet my phone's kernel still kills them.)

The workaround I did is to have a Llama event that relaunches the other four apps every 3 hours.  The fourth app is tricky because Screebl doesn't turn on when launched.  So far so good. **The problem is .. if the kernel kills Llama.**

I'm looking for a timed launcher, I think.  It needs to launch Llama every 3 hours, so that llama can launch the other four apps, *and this timed launcher*, every 3 hours.  The set-up is sort of like those old Windows viruses that come in two executables; each exe makes sure the other is always running.  I cross my fingers the kernel doesn't kill them both.

I'm looking for suggestions.  How do I keep given apps always running?

P.S. Heh, I see that this is the opposite of [this community wikied question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30332/how-can-i-stop-applications-and-services-from-running).

Comment: Android's ActivityManager usually kills and restarts services after some time (usually a few mins) that were killed because of low-memory. I suspect that if this mechanism failes your device is in a situation where it has very low resources and a different workaround wouldn't help either.

Comment: So your device already kills background service due to low memory -- and you want to solve that by adding another background service? Not very likely to work, wouldn't you agree? But you might want to check [Keeping an app in memory](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28220/16575) and [A: How to lower OOM value of an app permanently?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/23469/16575)